# Eclipse unable to connect to TFS Server

Tags: eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin, team-explorer, team-explorer-everywhere

I am using eclipse with Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere 2010.  I was able to successfully import my Project, but every time I open eclipse, The progress window gets stuck at 60% while trying to "Refresh TFS Server Information for http://my.server".

Eventually I will get an error from eclipse:

An internal error occured during:"refreshing server item information for project MyProject".
com.ctc.wstc.exc.WstxIOException: Connection reset.

Also I get this messagewhen trying to refresh manually:
An internal error occured during:"Refreshing TFS Server information for http://my.server".
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.Wstx.LazyException] Connection reset.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling and re-installing eclipse and TEE plug-in.  After that everything connects and works as far as TFS is concerned.

Answer (score 3):

The "Connection reset" is coming from TEE's network communication layer and message points to a network problem.  Can you use any TFS features from the plug-in (is "Refresh Server Item Information" the only thing that fails)?  If you can't use any TFS features from the plug-in, check that Eclipse's HTTP proxy configuration is correct.

If you can use some TFS features, but the server item information refresh feature is failing, check that you don't have an HTTP proxy, firewall, or NAT device between your client and TFS that is dropping TCP sockets after a short time.  Refreshing information for a large number of files, or from a heavily loaded server, may take a while (perhaps minutes).  A network device that "drops" the active TCP socket without notifying the client would cause this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

First, install [TEE SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=25125) if you didn't already.

If the error persists, it might be a potential bug so post it on [connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) or on the [TEE forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tee/threads).